# TabActivity Always loading first tab on orientation change

Tags: android

A tabactivity has 3 tabs in it. in onCreate() after adding tabs programatically, there is a call to  `tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);setDefaultTab(currentTab);` To display a specific tab. However, This statement has no effect when orientation is changed and onCreate() is called. The tabactivity always shows first tab. How to set a specific tab on orientation change?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `setCurrentTab(x)` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` where `x` is the last selected tab. When device changes orientation activities are recreated. So when activity is about to be destroyed you have to save its state and restore it when it's recreated. [onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is where you save the state. Override this method and put currently selected tab to outState. Then in [onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) you get currently selected tab from `savedInstanceState`. Actually `outState = savedInstanceState`. Basically this how it's done.

Comment: I am already doing this, the problem is that setCurrentTab is ignored or superseeded when activity is created after an orientation change.